# Strange PHP behavior only on IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I've got one hell of a challenge for you today.

Please visit: http://catalogue.anp.ca/products/

Using Internet Explorer, you get, at the end of the source code:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: open(/services/webdata/php_sessions/sess_1baadca499c102cae0796f91e6aa45e6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/services/webdata/php_sessions) in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

But it never happens if you use another browser. It only happens on IE.

Further more, note that this is a PHP error, so there must be something going on with IE, like in the headers or something. I flushed all my data, cookies, passwords, session data, history everything and the error still pops out.

Usually, this error is related to permissions on the server, but in this case the server is supposed to work fine, in fact, it does work fine for all other browsers except IE.

Can anyone give me pointers as to what is happening?

**EDIT:
NOTE, before more people try to answer, DISPLAY_ERRORS is now off, you will never get the error anymore, don't post to say that you don't see the error**

Just try and see if you can come up with a valid reason why only IE shows this error. I'm leaving this open just out of curiosity...

Comment: Reeks of a server configuration issue. The hard disk may be full or the quota exceeded. I'm not getting it at all btw, not even IE

Comment: Strange, we all get it, all the time with IE on all machines even the ones that never went on the site and the client also gets it... Very fishy, anyone else can tell me that they don't see it WITH IE?

Comment: Yeah, definitely something up with your server.  It is probably a coincidence that you see it happen when you open it with IE.  The browser has nothing to do with sessions on your server.  As far as the browser it is concerned, there is just a cookie.  Perhaps in IE, you have cached the error message.

Comment: Just tested in IE9 and seeing no error here.

Comment: If the error message isn't cached as @Brad says, this is a server issue either way. Speaking to the server admin  might be the way to go

Comment: I tried hidding the errors by turning off display_errors, anyway this is a production server after all, should never show errors. Guess what, the error is not there anymore... So it is definitely not a caching issue... What a weird behavior... I'll leave this post open in case someone gets a real answer...

Comment: Server admin doesn't know why the error occurs, its a managed hosting on a trustful company and they don't get that for any other site... only for ours on IE

Comment: Very strange. ----------

Comment: Using IE 8.0.6001 I don't get those messages, but I do get an `error on page` warning with this data: `Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; CIBA; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Fri, 11 Nov 2011 03:22:12 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 78
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://anp.ca/mailpress`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was a caching issue but where, many new browsers we try don't show this error while all our old browsers still show it if i don't hide the errors... So i dedided to hide errors and it solved my weird problem...

Answer (score 0):

**Snarky Answer**

You first opened it in Firefox. Then, the process of creating a new session became corrupted on your computer (permission error or php.ini error?). Then, you tried IE. The error showed up at that point, but wouldn't show up for other browsers because the session had already been created.

**Constructive Idea**

Use "Developer tools" in IE and Firefox (or send "requests" to a listening telnet that you have open on another port). Diff the two requests. Off the top of my head, I feel like the only difference will be the User-Agent, though maybe it will give you some insight.

Comment: The website is getting accessed all day long by different users, not just me and no i'm not losing my session data for a weird reason... I can open a session in my catalog and i'm still connected on each page even with that error going... Thanks for trying